# Remove submitted state in submission handler

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-8

I am trying to reset a form so that it appears to Drupal 8 that it hasn't been submitted. So far I have been unable to do this, as I cannot find any available methods (setSubmitted() hardcodes it to TRUE without a FALSE option). The reason is this isn't a full submit, but a submit of one field after which I would like the user to be redirected to another page that has another form, and I would like this secondary form to use the value obtained in the first step.

In the submit handler for the first part I use this to redirect:

```
$form_state->setRedirect('my.route', [], []);
```

And this works, but when the form reaches the second form (it seems) that the second form thinks it is a submission. As a result any submit buttons I add to the second form seem to make it auto-submit, and this breaks my user journey.

In the submit for the first part I have tried:

```
$form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);
$form_state = new FormState();
unset($form_state);
```

Tried the above in various configurations to no avail. They all prevent/ignore the setRedirect call that I make afterwards. The reason I want/need to do it this way is I want to preserve the POST method used.

Comment: You might want to try the multistep form approach, have a look at this [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/93747/26231) and this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-multi-step-forms-in-drupal-8/).

Comment: @EricLavault Yes I have seen something similar to this. The issue is I need a block type of form and a page type form. Even though this is correctly a multistep, I believe the example you shared (and others I have seen) have the form refreshing on itself (using the same URL). For this use case I need the second part to take place at a different address, post the data to it and collect

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to obtain something similar to what core search module does? It has simple [`SearchBlockForm`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21search%21src%21Form%21SearchBlockForm.php/class/SearchBlockForm/8.4.x) that sends data to more complex [`SearchPageForm`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21search%21src%21Form%21SearchPageForm.php/class/SearchPageForm/8.4.x).

`SearchBlockForm` uses `GET` method (though you may use `POST`):

```
$form['#method'] = 'get';
```

and [has no id and token fields](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21search%21search.module/function/search_form_search_block_form_alter/8.4.x):

```
function search_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['form_build_id']['#access'] = FALSE;
  $form['form_token']['#access'] = FALSE;
  $form['form_id']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```

BTW, the last change allows you to avoid running submit callbacks.

Hope this helps.